# Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I downloaded the Xcode 8 beta and converted my syntax to Swift 3. When I did, I got the eponymous error with this code (this didn't happen before):

Swift 3:

```
do {
    let fileAttributes = try FileManager.default().attributesOfItem(atPath: fileURL.path!) // Error here
    let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes[NSFileSize] as! NSNumber
    fileSize = fileSizeNumber.longLongValue
} catch _ as NSError {
    print("Filesize reading failed")
}
```

Swift 2:

```
do {
    let fileAttributes = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(fileURL.path!)
    let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes[NSFileSize] as! NSNumber
    fileSize = fileSizeNumber.longLongValue
} catch _ as NSError {
    print("Filesize reading failed")
}
```

Is this a bug in Swift 3, or am I missing something?

I know there are many questions about the same error, but those don't fix my problem. I'm happy to edit for clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get this error in playground. Can you provide more code around this? And the original Swift 2.2 code.

Comment: @EricD No; this error comes up before I can build/run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
do {
    let fileAttributes = try FileManager.default().attributesOfItem(atPath: file.path!)
    if let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes["NSFileSize"] as? NSNumber {
        let fileSize = fileSizeNumber.int64Value

    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Filesize reading failed: \(error.debugDescription)")
}
```

Since `NSFileSize` was just a constant string I've replaced it by its raw value. It seems ok - but it would be better to find the official equivalent, of course (which I didn't manage to for now, so don't take this solution for granted, it's just a workaround).

*Update for Xcode 8 GM:*

Using `FileAttributeKey.size` is better than using the hardcoded constant (thanks [@rudy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890205/rudy) for the reminder). Here's an updated example:

```
do {
    let attributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: file.path)
    if let size = attributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as? NSNumber {
        let fileSize = size.int64Value
        print(fileSize)
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I've found the list of constants: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys but this documentation hasn't been updated to Swift 3 yet.

Comment: I think you'll find that NSFileSize.rawValue will get you a better result, since the name of the constant isn't guaranteed to be the same as the actual string it represents.

Comment: @rudy You're right about hardcoded values. I've udpated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Swift 3:

```
var fileSize: UInt64 // size in bytes

do {
    let fileAttributes: NSDictionary? = try FileManager.default().attributesOfItem(atPath: fileURL.path!)
    if let fileSizeNumber = fileAttributes?.fileSize() { fileSize = fileSizeNumber }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Filesize reading failed: \(error.debugDescription)")
}
```

By casting the attributes into NSDictionary, many built-in methods become available including .fileSize():

- `.fileGroupOwnerAccountName()`
- `.fileModificationDate()`
- `.fileOwnerAccountName()`
- `.filePosixPermissions()`
- `.fileSize()`
- `.fileSystemFileNumber()`
- `.fileSystemNumber()`
- `.fileType()`

It's easy to discover their return data types by inspecting them with option-Click in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

This works on the Dictionary as returned from the call:

```
fileAttributes[FileAttributeKey.size.rawValue]
```

(Swift 3 as of XCode8 WWDC)