# swift 3.0 Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, swift

I get an image from a `URL` and set the image to `UIImageView` and cache dictionary.
But when I set the image to the dictionary, I got this error: swift 3.0 Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'.

```
var imageCache = Dictionary<String, UIImage>()
func getImage(url: String, imageView: UIImageView) {
    let image = self.imageCache[url] as UIImage?
    if image == nil {
        let url = URL(string:url)!
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: req as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if data != nil && error == nil {
                let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
                imageView.image = image
                self.imageCache[url] = image //******* Here got the error!
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } else {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874157/error-ambiguous-reference-to-member-subscript-in-swift-3)

Comment: @RemyCilia really not a same problem

Comment: Since you don't use the URLRequest at all delete the line `let req ...` and pass `url` as first parameter of the data task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using key as `URL`, it wont work, change it to `url.absoluteString` because you declare your Dictionary key as string

Comment: Thanks very much, that works. But my param url is also String class, why it not works.

Comment: because you override the url variable with another `URL` type variable with the same name, you can change `url: String` to other things like `urlString: String` then use `urlString` for the key

Comment: yeah, I miss this. It's a stupid error. Thanks very much.